# Liquibase Postgres error when creating hstore index

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have the following part of `Liquibase` changeset that creates index on a hstore column.

```
        CREATE INDEX index_name ON ${schemaName}.table_name ((attributes->'dataset'));
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore -> unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 109
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
```

The hstore extensions is installed as I've checked it.

The engine version is 12.5 on AWS RDS instance.

This was written for postgres 9.6, so I believe it should work without any issues when it comes to combatibility.

Jdbc driver for postgres is in version of `42.2.18`

Comment: What happens if you do `(attributes->'dataset::text')`? Also I have to believe the JDBC driver is 42.2.18.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver apparently the issue was with liquibase version. I was using 3.10.X. Heard from other colleague that it requires 3.5.X to work. Tried and works without any issues. I didn't expect liquibase to be depended so much. However just out of curiosity I will check your suggestion.